# Blocking Access to Specific Sites For Certain Alternate Access Mappings

Tags: security, alternate-access-mapping

Ok, so I'm not sure that this is entirely possible, but wanted to pose the question: would it be possible to block access to certain content when the site is accessed from a certain alternate access map?

When accessing the site internally, we should be able to see everything.  However, if we access the site from outside our network via a different alternate access map, certain content under the same web application would be blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only method I have found to do this is outside of SharePoint.  In our particular case, our F5 load-balancer can filter certain content on one endpoint but allow the same content on another endpoint.  Since no other solutions have been presented, marking this as the answer: SharePoint itself cannot do it.